# Why is it called "Match Point"?

Tags: title, match-point

This movie is about a married man killing a beautiful woman, because she is pregnant with his child. Why is it called *Match Point*?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Plot spoiler:

> The character wants to disguise his murder as a robbery. He gets rid of the loot (jewellery) by launching it in the river. However an item just touches a barrier, and it can fall on one side or the other.

This will decide the fate of the man, and it is the same situation as when a tennis ball, during match point, touches the net and pure luck will decide outcome of the game.

Answer (score 16):

The title of the film is simply a play on words.

The main character, Chris Wilton is a retired Tennis Professional.  The fact that he murders his mistress and gets away with the crime is considered [Match Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Match_Point).

**Simple Definition of match point in tennis terms defined by [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/match%20point):**

> : a situation in tennis in which one player or team can win the match
>   by winning the next point
>
> : the final point that must be won to win a
>   match in tennis

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is because the male protagonist was a former tennis professional, and "Match Point" is a tennis term.